# Selecting distinct columns in two hive tables

Tags: hive

I have two hive tables as follows:

```
    names
id     name
1      mark
2      smith
3      john
4      robin

    Names
id     name
3      john
4      smith
5      tailor
6      will
```

I want to join the tables so that the resultant set should contain the non overlapping values of both first and second tables.

```
  id      name
  1       mark
  2       smith
  5       tailor
  6       will
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If yes, please show us... Otherwise this question won't attract many views, I guess. The table structure of **both** tables could help a lot, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try with [**`Full outer join`**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins) and then filter only the **`null records`** from the resultant set then apply **`coalesce`** function to get non null value for the columns.

***Example:***

```
select coalesce(tmp.id,tmp1.id)id,
       coalesce(tmp.name,tmp1.name)name 
from table1 full outer join table2 
      on table1.id = table2.id 
where table1.id is null or table2.id is null;
```

***Result:***

```
+---+------+
| id|  name|
+---+------+
|  1|  mark|
|  6|  will|
|  5|tailor|
|  2| smith|
+---+------+
```